# JavaScript .replace not working correctly with uni-codes

Tags: javascript

When trying to replace text like "hello" with uni-codes like "ᕼEᒪᒪO"
The code does not work correctly.

```js
    function nameback(name){
    return name.replace(/a/g, 'ᗩ').replace(/b/g, 'ᗷ').replace(/c/g, 'ᑕ').replace(/d/g,     'ᗪ').replace(/e/g, 'E').replace(/f/g, 'ᖴ').replace(/g/g, 'G').replace(/h/g, 'ᕼ').replace(/i/g, 'I').replace(/j/g, 'ᒍ').replace(/k/g, 'K').replace(/l/g, 'ᒪ').replace(/m/g, 'ᗰ').replace(/n/g, 'ᑎ').replace(/o/g, 'O').replace(/p/g, 'ᑭ').replace(/q/g, 'ᑫ').replace(/r/g, 'ᖇ').replace(/s/g, 'ᔕ').replace(/t/g, 'T').replace(/u/g, 'ᑌ').replace(/v/g, 'ᐯ').replace(/w/g, 'ᗯ').replace(/x/g, '᙭').replace(/y/g, 'Y').replace(/z/g, 'ᘔ').replace(/A/g, 'ᗩ').replace(/B/g, 'ᗷ').replace(/C/g, 'ᑕ').replace(/D/g, 'ᗪ').replace(/E/g, 'E').replace(/F/g, 'ᖴ').replace(/G/g, 'G').replace(/H/g, 'ᕼ').replace(/I/g, 'I').replace(/J/g, 'ᒍ').replace(/K/g, 'K').replace(/L/g, 'ᒪ').replace(/M/g, 'ᗰ').replace(/N/g, 'ᑎ').replace(/O/g, 'O').replace(/P/g, 'ᑭ').replace(/Q/g, 'ᑫ').replace(/R/g, 'ᖇ').replace(/S/g, 'ᔕ').replace(/T/g, 'T').replace(/U/g, 'ᑌ').replace(/V/g, 'ᐯ').replace(/W/g, 'ᗯ').replace(/X/g, '᙭').replace(/Y/g, 'Y').replace(/Z/g, 'ᘔ')
    }

    function myFunction(){
      console.log(nameback(document.getElementById("input").value))
    }

// test
console.log(nameback('hello'))
```

It just logs á•¼Eá’ªá’ªO
Any idea why this is happening?
I have the code stored in a separate file because its a chrome extention.

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: @Aplet123 the code is stored in a separate file. I'm using it for a chrome extention.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add:

```
charset="utf-8"
```